# Links in the notification bar should support being opened in a new tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, usability, notification-bar

The links in some of the notification bars are not middle-clickable ('open in background tab'). It works for the 'learn more' when gaining more privileges, but for example not the link to the FAQ for: "Welcome to Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development -- check out the FAQ!"

This is a usability bug.

Comment: Would edit, don't have points yet. To my suprise, those aren't actually hyperlinks - they are `<a>` tags, yes, but without `href`. Definitely a usability bug - "we want you to *left* click, no matter what *your* browsing habits are". (not to mention that this form of a non-link hyperlink seems it was harder to program than an actual hyperlink; didn't it *have* the hyperlinks at one time?)

Comment: Some messages have 'real' hyperlinks, others do not, which is really what confuses me most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch!

I changed it so we do both the JavaScript `onclick` and the `href` so both cases are covered.