# Privileges cannot be opened in new tab

Tags: feature-request, privileges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Similar to [this already completed "bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70772/links-in-the-notification-bar-should-support-being-opened-in-a-new-tab), one cannot open privilege details in a new tab.

This is applicable to both the [/help/privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and the achievements dropdown in the top-bar

In my opinion this too is a usability-bug

Comment: Achievements drop down items are opened in new tab by middle clicking so this applies only for the rows in [privileges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Don't think it's a bug, feature request asking to change the behavior is totally reasonable.

Comment: `<div data-href="/help/privileges/create-posts"` why was it done like this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone fixed this at some point. I cannot reproduce this anymore.

Assuming [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).